# Ruby: Different ways to declare a method on a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone explain me the difference between this 3 (apparently) same examples in Ruby?

**Code #1**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def something
        ....
    end
end
```

**Code #2**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def User.something
        ....
    end
end
```

**Code #3**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.something
        ....
    end
end
```

Comment: see [this](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) article on `class methods` vs `instance methods`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def something
      # ....
    end

    def User.something

    end

    def self.something

    end
end
```

here the first one is an instance method , which can be called only with instance of User

```
ex: User.new.something
```

the other two methods are class methods(also called singleton methods). Which can be called only on User class.

```
ex: User.something
```

there is also one more way to call class methods

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   class << self
     def something
       "wolf"
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: So it is safe to say that example #2 and #3 are **EXACTLY** the same?

Comment: yah right! they are the member of same singleton or ghost class. Here singleton is the class of User object.

Comment: Actually all the class methods and object's single ton methods are stored in a singleton class which is also called Eigen class or unknown class. The method lookup starts from there when you call a method

Comment: I guess we could say class methods are kinda like "static" methods in other languages. Thank you!

Comment: ghost class as well @Kranthi :)

Comment: Yep, thought of adding that word but missed out somehow.

Comment: No, they are completely und utterly *unlike* static methods. In particular, they aren't dispatched statically, they are dispatched dynamically. There is only one kind of method, they are just regular instance methods of the singleton class of an object which just happens to be a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def something
    ....
  end
end
```

Answer: this method will be available to this class's instance/object's singleton class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def User.something
        ....
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.something
        ....
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    class << self
        def something
            .......
        end
    end
end
```

These last 3 methods are defined to class level. Basically, classes are object so programmatically they will be only available to those class.  If you don't mind I would like to suggest you to watch the following video.
[The Ruby Object Model and Metaprogramming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=io34q2G4eOU&list=PLDOo4JBO2P5_Tjug8Yl7PANb0sZtO7R_D)

Comment: You lost me at the end of your answer

Comment: okey let me remove that. But watch the video link I provided. You will like that and get more constructive ideas about ruby object which more important to understand first. So these question will be clear to you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=io34q2G4eOU&list=PLDOo4JBO2P5_Tjug8Yl7PANb0sZtO7R_D